# Get certain number of characters after a delimiter in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need to extract certain number of characters from the detailed string field in db table.

sub_str will not work because it ask for position and in this case position is different in every row.

split_part will not work as it will return the complete part after delimiter and we just need 6 characters

Example of values            :                                           Expected Result:

```
461/5-6 srj pt no 101 B up ml to dn ml                      101 B   
461/5-6 srj pt no107A up ml to up loop line                 107A
461/5-6 srj pt no 102 A dn ml to dn loop line               102 A
461/6-7 srj pt no 107 B up loop line up ml                  107 B
461/6-7 gf 10 dn loop to dead end                           10
461/7-8 srj of ds gf 13 B machine siding to up loop line    13 B
461/7-8 srj gf 10A machine siding to dn loop line           10A
```

and so on.

Comment: What's the conditions here? Why you need just `10` in the 5th string?

Comment: Would you pease elaborate on the parsing logic?

Comment: You really have to explain your pattern more detailed. What should we tell the database to call? E.g. Why should the result be `10` and not `10 dn`? Currently the most fitting pattern could be: The first digit letters after the first space. But I cannot evaluate how the letter is treated. Give out only A or B if it is the next non whitespace character?

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the expected output for the shown examples. But, in fact, I don't know if this might work for your complete data set because you didn't describe the pattern well enough.

My idea:
After the first space there are some letters and spaces. The first digit numbers are taken followed by an optional space and the letter `A` or `B` if exist:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fe31ee7a163d402d298fa6352b919a37)

```
SELECT
    (regexp_matches(mytext, '^.* [a-z ]+(\d+ ?[AB]?)'))[1]
FROM
    texts
```